# Integral equation corresponding to Initial Value Problem.

Tags: initial-value-problems, integral-equations

The Initial Value problem $$y’’+y=0,y(0)=1,y’(0)=0$$ is equivalent to integral equation

$(A)$. $y(x)=1+\int_0^x(t-x)y(t)dt$

$( B)$. $y(x)=1+\int_0^x(t+x)y(t)dt$

$ (C)$. $y(x)=1+\int_0^x(tx)y(t)dt$

$(D)$. $y(x)=1+\int_0^x(x +t)y(t)dt$

If I assume $y’’=u(x) $ then by integration from $0$ to $x$ I got $$y’-y’(0)=\int_0^x u(t)dy$$ so that $$y’=\int_0^x u(t)dt$$ Again integration I got
$$y=1+\int_0^x(x-t)u(t)dt$$ which i put in given differential equation I got $$u(x)=-1+\int_0^x(t-x)u(t)dt$$ But no option matches . Where I did mistake? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it carefully. Integrating the ODE, and using $y'(0)=0$, we find
$$
y'(x)=-\int_0^xy(t)\,dt. \tag{1}
$$
Integrating again, and using $y(0)=1$, we obtain
$$
y(x)=1-\int_0^x\int_0^{x'}y(t)\,dt\,dx'. \tag{2}
$$
Interchanging the order of integration, we obtain
$$
y(x)=1-\int_0^x\int_t^xy(t)\,dx'\,dt =
1-\int_0^xy(t)(x-t)\,dt, \tag{3}
$$
which is equivalent to option $(A)$.

Let's check the result:
$$
y'(x)=-y(x)(x-x)-\int_0^xy(t)\,dt=-\int_0^xy(t)\,dt \\
\implies y''(x)=-y(x) \implies y''(x)+y(x)=0. \quad\checkmark
$$

Answer (score 1):

By cheating knowing the solution:
\begin{align}
y(x)&=\cos x\\
&=1+(\cos x-1)\\
&=1-\int_0^x\sin tdt\\
&=1+\left[-\left.(t-x)\sin t\right\rvert_0^x-\int_0^x\sin t dt\right]\\
&=1+\int_0^x(t-x)\cos tdt\\
&=1+\int_0^x(t-x)y(t)dt
\end{align}